# Get the tighest bounding box

Tags: c, compare, bounding-box, octree

I think the code is self explanatory:

```
// Set the bbox min and max of the lower node
current_min_bound = lower_get_bbox_min(buf, lower_handle);
current_max_bound = lower_get_bbox_max(buf, lower_handle);
// Set lower node bbox 
if(current_min_bound.x > leaf_node->bbox_min.x) {
    current_min_bound.x = leaf_node->bbox_min.x;
} 
if(current_min_bound.y > leaf_node->bbox_min.y) {
    current_min_bound.y = leaf_node->bbox_min.y;
}
if(current_min_bound.z > leaf_node->bbox_min.z) {
    current_min_bound.z = leaf_node->bbox_min.z;
}
if(current_max_bound.x < leaf_node->origin.x + highest_voxel_coord.x) {
    current_max_bound.x = leaf_node->origin.x + highest_voxel_coord.x;
}
if(current_max_bound.y < leaf_node->origin.y + highest_voxel_coord.y) {
    current_max_bound.y = leaf_node->origin.y + highest_voxel_coord.y;
}
if(current_max_bound.z < leaf_node->origin.z + highest_voxel_coord.z) {
    current_max_bound.z = leaf_node->origin.z + highest_voxel_coord.z;
}
lower_set_bbox_min(buf, lower_handle, current_min_bound);
lower_set_bbox_max(buf, lower_handle, current_max_bound);
```

So I would like to know if there is a faster way to compare and get the tighest bounding box in a given 3D coord system? I think so many comparations are killing my CPU performance here. The data structure is a tree but I think it doesn't matter for this problem.

Cheers.

Whether it is possible to code a faster way to calculate the math problem.

EDIT:

It looks like using the ternary conditional operator allows compiler to optimize the code:

```
                // Set lower node bbox min
                current_min_bound.x = (current_min_bound.x > leaf_node->origin.x + lowest_voxel_coord.x) ? leaf_node->origin.x + lowest_voxel_coord.x : current_min_bound.x;
                current_min_bound.y = (current_min_bound.y > leaf_node->origin.y + lowest_voxel_coord.y) ? leaf_node->origin.y + lowest_voxel_coord.y : current_min_bound.y;
                current_min_bound.z = (current_min_bound.z > leaf_node->origin.z + lowest_voxel_coord.z) ? leaf_node->origin.z + lowest_voxel_coord.z : current_min_bound.z;
                // Set lower node bbox max
                current_max_bound.x = (current_max_bound.x < leaf_node->origin.x + highest_voxel_coord.x) ? leaf_node->origin.x + highest_voxel_coord.x : current_max_bound.x;
                current_max_bound.y = (current_max_bound.y < leaf_node->origin.y + highest_voxel_coord.y) ? leaf_node->origin.y + highest_voxel_coord.y : current_max_bound.y;
                current_max_bound.z = (current_max_bound.z < leaf_node->origin.z + highest_voxel_coord.z) ? leaf_node->origin.z + highest_voxel_coord.z : current_max_bound.z;
```

Iterations: 27 546

Same iterations previous code: 0.860708 in seconds
Same iterations current code: 0.717957 in seconds

Comment: If it ain't broke, don't fix it. Profile your code first.

Comment: Edit for ternary conditional operator. Thanks!
- "Do you compile with optimization, e.g. -O2". 
- Yes I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Branch prediction failure can slow things down.

You could try "branchless" comparisons:

```
static int min( int x, int y ) { return y ^ ((x^y) & -(x<y)); }
static int max( int x, int y ) { return y ^ ((x^y) & -(x>y)); }
```

Leaving it to you to convert these to macros, perhaps.

Comment: It seems like this code is as fast as my edit section code! 
For the same iterations 27 546 it takes 0.717617 seconds.
Thanks!